# "Connection refused" when connecting Ganache with Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, http, sockets, websocket

I'm trying to create a simple dapp with Flutter. I'm using Solidity to create a simple contract and I'm using Ganache to test our contract. But there is a problem. I get a `"Connection refused"` error when I try to connect Ganache. When I start my application in debug mode, I noticed that it connects to ganache via a different PORT number each time instead of the current PORT number (7545). I disabled the Windows Network firewall but the problem is still not resolved. `Truffle compile` and `Truffle migrate` commands are working. I tried different ip addresses but it still doesn't work.

[image]

**Here is my ContractLinking class:**

```
class ContractLinking extends ChangeNotifier {
  static const String _ip = "127.0.0.1";
  static const String _port = "7545";
  final String _rpcUrl = "http://$_ip:$_port";
  final String _wsUrl = "ws://$_ip:$_port/";
  final String _privateKey =
      "0x8607478a7616d4c1b1a8ebbf956a640035225c988a09196af941a0be4a05296f";

  late Web3Client _client;

  bool isLoading = true;
  // bool get isLoading => isLoading;

  late Credentials _credentials;

  late DeployedContract _contract;

  late ContractFunction _getContrct;
  late ContractFunction _setContract;
  late ContractFunction _increseNumber;
  late ContractFunction _getNumber2;

  BigInt? deployedNumber;
  BigInt? getNumber2Int;
  late String deployedName;

  ContractLinking(context) {
    initialSetup(context);
  }

  initialSetup(context) async {
    _client = Web3Client(_rpcUrl, Client(), socketConnector: () {
      return IOWebSocketChannel.connect(_wsUrl).cast<String>();
    });
    final String abiStringFile =
        await rootBundle.loadString("src/artifacts/HelloFlutter.json");
    final jsonAbi = jsonDecode(abiStringFile);
    final abiCode = jsonEncode(jsonAbi["abi"]);

    final contractAddress =
        EthereumAddress.fromHex(jsonAbi["networks"]["5777"]["address"]);

    _credentials = EthPrivateKey.fromHex(_privateKey);

    _contract = DeployedContract(
        ContractAbi.fromJson(abiCode, "HelloFlutter"), contractAddress);

    _getContrct = _contract.function("getNumber");
    _setContract = _contract.function("set");
    _increseNumber = _contract.function("increaseNumber");
    _getNumber2 = _contract.function("number2");
    getNumber2();
  }

  Future<void> getNumber2() async {
    final response = await _client
        .call(contract: _contract, function: _getNumber2, params: []);
    getNumber2Int = response[0];
    isLoading = false;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> increaseNumber() async {
    isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();
    final response = _client.sendTransaction(
        _credentials,
        Transaction.callContract(
            contract: _contract, function: _increseNumber, parameters: []));
    isLoading = false;
    getNumber2();
  }

  Future<void> getNumber() async {
    final response = await _client.call(
      contract: _contract,
      function: _getContrct,
      params: [],
    );
    deployedNumber = response[0];
    isLoading = false;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> setContractFunction(BigInt value) async {
    isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();
    await _client.sendTransaction(
        _credentials,
        Transaction.callContract(
            contract: _contract, function: _setContract, parameters: [value]));
    isLoading = false;

    getNumber();
  }
}
```

Comment: Is your truffle-config.js file correctly configured?